# MySQL LIKE IN()?

Tags: sql, mysql

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM fiberbox f WHERE f.fiberBox LIKE '%1740 %' OR f.fiberBox LIKE '%1938 %' OR f.fiberBox LIKE '%1940 %'
```

I did some looking around and can't find anything similar to a LIKE IN() - I envision it working like this:

```
SELECT * FROM fiberbox f WHERE f.fiberbox LIKE IN('%140 %', '%1938 %', '%1940 %')
```

Any ideas? Am I just thinking of the problem the wrong way - some obscure command I've never seen.

MySQL 5.0.77-community-log

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(f.fiberbox, "1740,1938,1940")`

Comment: FIND_IN_SET does not accept wildcards like `%`

Answer (score 582, accepted):

A [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) *might* be more efficient, but you'd have to benchmark it to be sure, e.g.

```
SELECT * from fiberbox where field REGEXP '1740|1938|1940';
```

Comment: I like this answer - quick, simple, got all of the "options" in one line like I wanted (easy to edit). On the small result set I am targeting, no decrease in performance at all.

Comment: Over 1 million rows in my table. REGEX arround 0.0009 and LIKE arround 0.0005. If more then 5 REGEX, arround 0.0012...

Comment: I had an issue where `REGEXP` was prohibitively slow, but I needed the flexibility of REGEXP to narrow my result set further than `LIKE` could provide. I came up with a hybrid solution where I used both `LIKE` and `REGEXP`; despite the `REGEXP` portion being sufficient to give me the correct results, using `LIKE` as well allowed MySQL to reduce the result set considerably before having to use the slower `REGEXP` criteria.

Comment: To get the regexp value from a column: `(select group_concat(myColumn separator '|') from..)`

Comment: i thought (Regexp) it's another part of the mysql extension,... but the fact it isn't. Because it is a part of the main program. very good then :D

Comment: Adding to the performance data. On MySql 5.5 in a table with 229M rows, a 1 term left anchored 3 char search: REGEXP: 16s, LIKE: 8.5s; 2 terms: REGEXP: 22.1s, LIKE: 9.69; '^(hemoglobin|hematr?ocrit).*' vs 3 term like: REGEXP: 36.3, LIKE: 9.59.

Comment: @JesseClark - Can you possibly do a test for something like REGEXP '1024|9999|8888|7777' vs Like '%1024%', etc. To my understanding like '1024%' can be indexed while LIKE '%1024%' cannot be and REGEXP can't ever be, so comparing the performance output for the 2 will be a very strong hint for me how to deploy my current application. Thank you very much.

Comment: Will `. . . where field REGEXP '1740'` treat as `. . . where field like '%1740%'`? Or should I add `(.*)` surround the *REGEXP* one to make it the same as `%1740%`?

Comment: I am getting an error when one of the values in regex has characters.
Here is my Query. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE skills regexp 'C++|Javascript'`

Comment: @AmarjitSingh you will need to escape any special characters, e.g. C\+\+|Javascript. AFAIK MySQL has no built-in escaping function, but your programming langauge might, e.g. php has https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: @PaulDixon Thanks.
But I need to know characters that can Interfere with Mysql's regexp operator. I am using Node JS in this project.

Comment: I have asked a question here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression

Comment: I have a question can we use OR with REGEXP for searching in multiple fields ?

Comment: This does work as expected, but the query speed is not really comparable with the usage of multiple LIKE conditions combined with OR.

Answer (score 230):

Paul Dixon's answer worked brilliantly for me. To add to this, here are some things I observed for those interested in using REGEXP:

To Accomplish multiple LIKE filters with Wildcards:

```
 SELECT * FROM fiberbox WHERE field LIKE '%1740 %'
                           OR field LIKE '%1938 %'
                           OR field LIKE '%1940 %';
```

Use REGEXP Alternative:

```
 SELECT * FROM fiberbox WHERE field REGEXP '1740 |1938 |1940 ';
```

Values within REGEXP quotes and between the | (OR) operator are treated as wildcards. Typically, REGEXP will require wildcard expressions such as (.*)1740 (.*) to work as %1740 %.

If you need more control over placement of the wildcard, use some of these variants:

To Accomplish LIKE with Controlled Wildcard Placement:

```
SELECT * FROM fiberbox WHERE field LIKE '1740 %'
                          OR field LIKE '%1938 '
                          OR field LIKE '%1940 % test';
```

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM fiberbox WHERE field REGEXP '^1740 |1938 $|1940 (.*) test';
```

- Placing ^ in front of the value indicates start of the line.
- Placing $ after the value indicates end of line.
- Placing (.*) behaves much like the % wildcard.
- The . indicates any single character, except line breaks. Placing .
  inside () with * (.*) adds a repeating pattern indicating any number
  of characters till end of line.

There are more efficient ways to narrow down specific matches, but that requires more review of Regular Expressions. NOTE: Not all regex patterns appear to work in MySQL statements. You'll need to test your patterns and see what works.

Finally, To Accomplish Multiple LIKE and NOT LIKE filters:

```
SELECT * FROM fiberbox WHERE field LIKE '%1740 %'
                          OR field LIKE '%1938 %'
                          OR field NOT LIKE '%1940 %'
                          OR field NOT LIKE 'test %'
                          OR field = '9999';
```

Use REGEXP Alternative:

```
SELECT * FROM fiberbox WHERE field REGEXP '1740 |1938 |^9999$'
                          OR field NOT REGEXP '1940 |^test ';
```

OR Mixed Alternative:

```
SELECT * FROM fiberbox WHERE field REGEXP '1740 |1938 '
                          OR field NOT REGEXP '1940 |^test '
                          OR field NOT LIKE 'test %'
                          OR field = '9999';
```

Notice I separated the NOT set in a separate WHERE filter. I experimented with using negating patterns, forward looking patterns, and so on. However, these expressions did not appear to yield the desired results. In the first example above, I use ^9999$ to indicate exact match. This allows you to add specific matches with wildcard matches in the same expression. However, you can also mix these types of statements as you can see in the second example listed.

Regarding performance, I ran some minor tests against an existing table and found no differences between my variations. However, I imagine performance could be an issue with  bigger databases, larger fields, greater record counts, and more complex filters.

As always, use logic above as it makes sense.

If you want to learn more about regular expressions, I recommend www.regular-expressions.info as a good reference site.

Comment: Keep in mind that a field with the value NULL won't match REGEXP. You can use IFNULL to solve this problem. `WHERE IFNULL(field, '') NOT REGEXP '1740 | 1938'`

Comment: @DanyMarcoux What if i want to use (.*) but it should act like FIELDNAME LIKE '%%', how to use it with regexp, so that when an empty string is passed. it should fetch all the records..

Comment: The WHERE field NOT LIKE '%1940 %' OR field NOT LIKE 'test %' will always return all rows. That may perhaps have contributed to not yielding the desired results you mentioned?

Answer (score 19):

Regexp way with list of values

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field regexp concat_ws("|",
"111",
"222",
"333");
```

Answer (score 17):

You can create an inline view or a temporary table, fill it with you values and issue this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    fiberbox f
JOIN    (
        SELECT '%1740%' AS cond
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '%1938%' AS cond
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '%1940%' AS cond
        ) с
ON      f.fiberBox LIKE cond
```

This, however, can return you multiple rows for a `fiberbox` that is something like `'1740, 1938'`, so this query can fit you better:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    fiberbox f
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    (
                SELECT '%1740%' AS cond
                UNION ALL
                SELECT '%1938%' AS cond
                UNION ALL
                SELECT '%1940%' AS cond
                ) с
        WHERE   f.fiberbox LIKE cond
        )
```

Answer (score 9):

Sorry, there is no operation similar to `LIKE IN` in mysql.

If you want to use the LIKE operator without a join, you'll have to do it this way:

```
(field LIKE value OR field LIKE value OR field LIKE value)
```

You know, MySQL will not optimize that query, FYI.

Answer (score 9):

Just note to anyone trying the REGEXP to use "LIKE IN" functionality.

IN allows you to do:

```
field IN (
'val1',
'val2',
'val3'
)
```

In REGEXP this won't work

```
REGEXP '
val1$|
val2$|
val3$
'
```

It has to be in one line like this:

```
REGEXP 'val1$|val2$|val3$'
```

Answer (score 4):

This would be correct:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field regexp concat_ws("|",(
"111",
"222",
"333"
));
```

Comment: im getting operand should container 1 columns(s) on this approach

Answer (score 3):

Flip operands

```
'a,b,c' like '%'||field||'%'
```

Comment: when you have some field *explicitly* would equal something eg. an enum for grads _'a','b','c'_  but not _ab,ac or bc_  `create table x(en enum('a,b,c')));insert into x values('a'),('b')`en is only **a or b** doing this method by flipping oprands `select * from, x where 'a,c' like concat('%',en,'%')` can be safer in **SQL Injunction** no need to escape charactors like ***$^ etc.***

Comment: **This is NOT equivalent and WILL NOT WORK for general cases.** If you knew that `field` can only be exactly `a`, `b` or `c` then you should use `field IN ('a', 'b', 'c')`. But in general cases, this can NEVER replace `field LIKE '%a%' OR field LIKE '%b%' OR ...` because field itself can be something like `magic` which would make `'magic' LIKE '%a%'` true but the expression `'a,b,c' LIKE '%magic%'` false.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little tip:

I prefer to use the variant **RLIKE** (exactly the same command as **REGEXP**) as it sounds more like natural language, and is shorter; well, just 1 char.

The "R" prefix is for Reg. Exp., of course.

Comment: `RLIKE` is a synonym for `REGEXP` at least for [MariaDB RLIKE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rlike/)

Answer (score 2):

You can get desired result with help of [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html).

```
SELECT fiberbox from fiberbox where fiberbox REGEXP '[1740|1938|1940]';
```

We can test the above query please click [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30215/2)

```
SELECT fiberbox from fiberbox where fiberbox REGEXP '[174019381940]';
```

We can test the above query please click [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30215/1)

Comment: This is an incorrect regular expression. `[...]` is a *character set*, meaning that any of the characters in the set are enough to be seen as a match. So *any value* with the digits '`0`, `1`, `3`, `4`, `7`, `8`, `9` or the `|` pipe character will match this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is right. The proper way to format the REGEXP string is to remove the surrounding brackets. Just use something like `WHERE fiberbox REGEXP '1740|1938|1940'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this too:

```
 SELECT
    * 
FROM
    fiberbox f
    JOIN (
    SELECT
        substring_index( substring_index( '1740,1938,1940', ',', help_topic_id + 1 ), ',',- 1 ) AS sub_ 
    FROM
        mysql.help_topic 
    WHERE
        help_topic_id <(
            length( '1740,1938,1940' )- length(
            REPLACE ( '1740,1938,1940', ',', '' ))+ 1 
        ) AS b 
        ) ON f.fiberBox LIKE concat('%',
    b.sub_,
    '%')
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use like this too:

```
SELECT * FROM fiberbox WHERE fiber IN('140 ', '1938 ', '1940 ')
```

Comment: No, you can't, because this tests for *exact string matches*, not for substrings.