# Is there a way to combine IN and LIKE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I'm currently running a query like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM email
 WHERE email_address LIKE 'ajones@%'
    OR email_address LIKE 'bsmith@%'
    OR email_address LIKE 'cjohnson@%'
```

The large number of `OR`'s bothers me. Is there a way to condense this up with something akin to an `IN` operator, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
  FROM email 
 WHERE email_address LIKE ('ajones@%', 'bsmith@%', 'cjohnson@%')
```

Or is this just wishful thinking?

Comment: Yes there is something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I recommend: Extract the part of the email address before the `@` and use that before `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM `email`
WHERE LEFT(`email_address`, LOCATE('@', `email_address`) - 1)
        IN ('ajones', 'bsmith', 'cjohnson')
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `RLIKE` operator (synonym for `REGEXP`) as well.

```
SELECT *
  FROM email 
 WHERE email_address RLIKE 'ajones@|bsmith@|cjohnson@'
```

There might be some performance penalty due to regex matching, but for simple patterns or small sets it should be not an issue.
For more on RLIKE see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp