# Is there LIKE IN in mysql?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a combination of “LIKE” and “IN” in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql)

Is there LIKE IN in mysql?

Comment: I asked this my self some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014940/is-there-a-combination-of-like-and-in-in-sql

Comment: @Techpriester: THANK YOU!  I was sure I'd answered that recently, couldn't find the question...  I marked this as a duplicate because MySQL has native Full Text Search functionality, and there is no `LIKE IN` in SQL at all.

Answer (score 4):

No.

But there is [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). Maybe that goes into the right direction?

```
mysql> SELECT id, body   
    -> FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
    -> ('Keyword1 Keyword2 Keyword3');
```

Answer (score 4):

Per this prior stackoverflow question, you might have better luck with a REGEXP query:

[MySQL LIKE IN()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in)

Comment: +1 nice! It's going to be slow, but exactly what the OP wants (as far as can be told what he wants.)

Comment: This is valid, but Full Text Search (FTS) is a far better way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you may be able to use [RLIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) depending on your version of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could use REGEXP.

```
...WHERE field REGEXP 'abc|xyz'
```