# MySQL query results used in LIKE

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query to pull all the rows that contain a username from a large list of usernames in a field.

For example, the table contains a column called 'Worklog' which contains comments made by users and their username. I need to search that field for all user names that are contained in a list I have.

I have tried a few different things but can't get anything to work. So far, this is kind of what I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `JULY2010` 
WHERE `WorkLog` 
IN (
     SELECT CONCAT( '%', `UserName` , '%' ) 
     FROM `OpsAnalyst`
)
```

The problem is I need to use LIKE because it is searching a large amount of text, but I also have a large list that it is pulling from, and that list needs to be dynamic because the people that work here are changing frequently. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to use like? cant you just join the two tables?

Comment: look to this answer. meybe regexp help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in

Comment: @Tim I don't have anything that I can actually join the tables on. No common columns. Perhaps I misunderstand your answer? I'm kind of new to SQL and everything I've tried so far has been from what I've found searching Google for people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM `JULY2010` 
 WHERE `WorkLog`  REGEXP
  (SELECT CONCAT( `UserName`, '|') 
   FROM `OpsAnalyst`)
```

Comment: I get this error when performing this query:
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified this and used GROUP_CONCAT() and now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM JULY2010 
WHERE `WorkLog` 
REGEXP (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`UserName` SEPARATOR '|') FROM `OpsAnalyst`
)
```

I am now getting a result set, but it seems like it isn't as many results as I should be getting. I'm going to have to look into it a little more to figure out what the problem is