# 'LIKE ('%this%' OR '%that%') and something=else' not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a select query where I am trying to search strings for multiple patterns

```
LIKE ('%this%' or '%that%' ) and something=else
```

Returns zero results

However

```
LIKE '%this%' and something=else
```

returns results
and

```
LIKE '%that%' and something=else
```

returns result

Is it possible to get all my results into one query?  If a string matches both, how will it handle that?

Comment: If you had proper error checking you'd have gotten notified of the syntax error in the first query. At bare minimum you should have something like `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Great answer as tutorial in related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4808757/2906290

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It would be nice if you could, but you can't use that syntax in SQL.

Try this:

```
(column1 LIKE '%this%' OR column1 LIKE '%that%') AND something = else
```

Note the use of brackets! You need them around the `OR` expression.
Without brackets, it will be parsed as `A OR (B AND C)`,which won't give you the results you expect.

Comment: +1 Beat me by 57 seconds.  Another option to consider is Full Text Search (FTS)

Comment: Thanks!  The mistake seems so obvious once you know what it was :)

Answer (score 34):

Instead of using `LIKE`, use `REGEXP`. For example:

```
SELECT * WHERE value REGEXP 'THIS|THAT'
```

```
mysql> SELECT 'pi' REGEXP 'pi|apa';                     -> 1
mysql> SELECT 'axe' REGEXP 'pi|apa';                    -> 0
mysql> SELECT 'apa' REGEXP 'pi|apa';                    -> 1
mysql> SELECT 'apa' REGEXP '^(pi|apa)$';                -> 1
mysql> SELECT 'pi' REGEXP '^(pi|apa)$';                 -> 1
mysql> SELECT 'pix' REGEXP '^(pi|apa)$';                -> 0
```

Refer:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Much more clean and objective than using using multiple LIKES, indeed.

Comment: A more readable example: `SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE description REGEXP "dogs|cats"`

Answer (score 5):

Try something like:

`WHERE (column LIKE '%this%' OR column LIKE '%that%') AND something = else`

Answer (score 3):

Break out the `LIKE` clauses into 2 separate statements, i.e.:

```
(fieldname1 LIKE '%this%' or fieldname1 LIKE '%that%' ) and something=else
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have something against splitting it up?

```
...FROM <blah> 
   WHERE 
     (fieldA LIKE '%THIS%' OR fieldA LIKE '%THAT%') 
     AND something = else
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
(column LIKE '%this%' and something=else) or (column LIKE '%that%' and something=else)
```

Comment: While this will work (and may lead to the exact same plan after optimizations), the non-distributed form is generally preferred -- at least for human consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit old question but still people try to find efficient solution so instead you should use [FULLTEXT index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) (it's available from MySQL 5.6.4).

Query on table with +35mil records by triple `like` in where block took **~2.5s** but after adding index on these fields and using [BOOLEAN MODE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html) inside `match ... against ...` it took only **0.05s**.