# cakephp build query to filter on model OR associated model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to find rows by filtering on a table's column, ***OR*** on an associated table's column. I can get an AND version working, but I'm not sure how to change the condition between the `->where()` and the `->matching()` to OR.

In this example I want to find a user by either their username or their regular name. In this case a User `hasMany` Names.

```
$users = $this->Users->find()
    ->where(['username LIKE' => '%' . $search_term . '%'])
    ->matching('Names', function($q) use ($search_term){
        return $q->where(function($exp, $query) use ($search_term) {
            $full_name = $query->func()->concat([
                'first' => 'identifier', ' ',
                'last' => 'identifier'
            ]);
            return $exp->like($full_name, '%' . $search_term . '%');
        });
    })
    ->contain(['Names'])
    ->limit(10)
    ->all();
```

Comment: basic idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/6526961/1127933

Comment: It always helps if you specify the types of the involved associations, `hasMany`, `belongsTo`, etc., there's different solutions depending on the type.

Comment: oh, I didn't realize. In this case it is a User `hasMany` Names association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`matching()` creates `INNER` joins**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data), with the conditions applied in the join's `ON` clause, causing users to be filtered out if no matching names exist, hence you cannot use this to create the `OR` condition that you are looking for.

You could for example move your names check into a correlated subquery (a query that references columns of the outer query), and [**use it with `EXISTS`**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions), something along the lines of this:

```
$namesMatcher = $this->Users->Names
    ->find()
    ->select(['Names.id'])
    ->where(function($exp, $query) use ($search_term) {
        $full_name = $query->func()->concat([
            'Names.first' => 'identifier', ' ',
            'Names.last' => 'identifier'
        ]);

        return $exp
            ->equalFields('Names.user_id', 'Users.id')
            ->like($full_name, '%' . $search_term . '%');
    });

$users = $this->Users->find()
    ->where(function($exp, $query) use ($search_term, $namesMatcher) {
        return $exp
            ->or_(['Users.username LIKE' => '%' . $search_term . '%'])
            ->exists($namesMatcher);
    })
    ->contain(['Names'])
    ->limit(10)
    ->all();
```

The generated query would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    Users.id ...
FROM
    users Users
WHERE
    Users.username LIKE '%term%' OR
    EXISTS(
        SELECT
            Names.id
        FROM
            names Names
        WHERE
            Names.user_id = Users.id AND
            CONCAT(Names.first, ' ', Names.last) LIKE '%term%'
    )
```

This could also be solved using for example a `LEFT` join, so that the user records aren't being affected by the join (see [**`Query::leftJoinWith()`**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-leftjoinwith)), allowing you to create an `OR` condition accordingly, but since you do not seem to need further access to the names in the query, there's not really a point in selecting them.