# How to do a subquery against multiple phrases with LIKE or REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

I am trying to use a where clause with like on a column.  However I need it to use a subquery to search against multiple phrases.

This question is similar to [MySQL LIKE IN()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in)

Right now my query looks like this.

```
WHERE hashtag REGEXP 'indiana|iu|bloomington'
```

However I need to do a subquery where the string is so my query would be something like this

```
WHERE hashtag REGEXP (select name from hashtags where hid = 1)
```

The above line obviously doesn't work and I'm not sure if REGEXP would be best in this situation.  Is there a way to use LIKE or REGEXP against multiple strings using a subquery?  Perhaps there is a better way to do this without a subquery that I just don't see at the moment.  Any help or direction is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
WHERE hashtag REGEXP (select GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR '|') from hashtags where hid = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also JOIN on a REGEXP:

```
SELECT mt.hashtag, ht.name
  FROM mytable mt
  JOIN hashtags ht
    ON mt.hashtag REGEXP ht.name
 WHERE ht.hid = 1;
```