# Searching from a mysql database based on a string in php

Tags: mysql

I Have a string foo = "a,b". Now I want to search in the mysql database to get user_id while comparing the string to the likes field. The likes field has data in the format interest => a c v d b.
The different characters are seperated by a space. I tried Using like but the result was not upto the mark. How can I go about it?

This is my code

```
select user_id from users where interest like %foo%;
```

Comment: You need to change the query to `WHERE interest LIKE '%foo%' OR interest LIKE '%bar%' OR interest LIKE '%oof%'` etc. Unless you use an SQL builder you cannot use arrays directly like this (and SQL builders only work because they've made the code to do it for you).

Comment: Asked and answered already

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435225/array-in-mysql-where-like

Comment: you have an string "a,b,c,d,e,f...." and one interest field in DB which has space separated values (a b c d e f......). You want to compare each value of the string to each value of the interest field???

Answer (score 1):

MySql does not support multiple keyword search in set like field, you should add `OR` condition of each search keyword with `REGEXP`
if your format interest like=> `a,c,v,d,b` then you can use `FIND_IN_SET()` function otherwise `REGEXP` provide to exact search.

```
SELECT user_id FROM users 
WHERE interest REGEXP '[[:<:]]a[[:>:]]' AND interest REGEXP '[[:<:]]b[[:>:]]'
```

this query search only `a` and `b` in field not `aa`, `bbax`

`LIKE` does not support exact search.