# MySQL correct way of selecting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like the following

```
id    field_id     field_value         user_id
1     4           'london'             12
2     4           'manchester'         33
3     25          'accounting'         12
4     25          'web designer'       37
5     27          'food'               12
6     27          'wine'               34
```

MY problem now is that I need to query it in human terms as follow,

I need to split the table somehow on a select query so I can search like so,

I need to search all users, which have ("london") AND ("accounting" OR "web design) AND (food OR wine)

My problem is I cannot split the `field_value` to seperate "location", "job title", "interests" if they where on different fields I would find it easy to do, but as they are on the same field, I am finding it difficult to use the AND and OR combination,

If the questions is difficult to understand I will try and explain it further.
many thnx

Also I would not Mind if there is a combination of **php** and **mysql** solution :)

Comment: Are you using EAV pattern and you want to query by custom fields? As far as I understand you need to have a users table and table with custom fields for user, right? I don't quite understand the structure of your data.

Comment: The categories you are looking for ("location", "job title") are indicated by the `field_id`, right? If so, you can use sub queries which only select those categories and go on from there.

Comment: @tpete well, location is london manchester, job title web designer accounting, I can't make different tables, as this was an open source project and will create more problems that solve them this small problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing the problem because your table is designed using the [EAV (Entity–attribute–value model)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) (anti)pattern.

A better table design would be to have a table 'locations', a table 'job title' and a table 'interests'. It would also solve your problem.

However, you CAN work with this design, but it's a but more troublesome.

I need to search all users, which have ("london") AND ("accounting" OR "web design) AND (food OR wine)

```
SELECT y1.* 
FROM yourtable y1
JOIN yourtable y2
ON y1.USER_ID = y2.USER_ID
JOIN yourtable y3
ON y2.USER_ID = y3.USER_ID
WHERE y1.field_id = 4
AND y1.field_value = "london"
AND y2.field_id = 25
AND y2.field_value IN ("accounting", "web design")
AND y3.field_id = 27
AND y3.field_value IN ("food", "wine")
```

Comment: did you forget the `as` keyword? `... as y1`? or is that optional?

Comment: It's optional, but if you think it more clear, feel free to add it.

Comment: you should join on `user_id`, otherwise, the query won't return anything

Comment: Where was you the past two days lol,? I have tried everything, inner join, join, left join, so many combinations I new I was tooooo close to getting it done, but this does work :) || also if someone should want to use the `LIKE %%` on the `IN()` function should check this out :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in many thnks guys, muchly appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE user_id IN(SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE field_value LIKE '%london%')
    AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE field_value LIKE '%accounting%' OR field_value LIKE '%web design%')
    AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE field_value LIKE '%food%' OR field_value LIKE '%wine%')
```