# Query to select var REGEX MANY columns

Tags: mysql, regex, performance, database-performance

Here is what I was want to Optimize this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
where `username` like "%abc%" 
   or `name`     like "%abc%" 
   or `email`    like "%abc%"
```

This search get result from users where any of `username` , `name` , `email` `like %abc%`

So I tried to use in with like **But**

I was looking for mysql Like in and I have found this answer  [stackoverflow :Mysql like in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in)

So the solution was **regex**

But I want to make the regex not use OR

I want to be like this

```
SELECT * from users where abc REGEXP 'username|name|email';
```

So the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? >>

```
SELECT * from users where CONCAT(username, ',', name, ',', email) REGEXP 'abc'
```

Comment: Your query is very good for me , and the same result work with LIKE statment Is there any diffrent between regex and like with your query

Comment: @MonaAbdelmajeed - Your question asks for regex solution, so I used `REGEXP` in the example. In this case, you will get same results if you use `like` or `REGEXP`. However for more complex search/match patterns `REGEXP` is better choice...