# How to make MySQL query more efficient using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script where I'm trying to match the [droppable data](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/249/) I retrieved in the form of an ajax $.post request that contains a firstname, lastname, description and grade and match it with that of the same data in my database. In doing so I want to find the user and fetch them out in my query. I'm having trouble making an efficient query using `LIKE` and am unsure what other component to add to make this happen correctly

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])){
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tempusers`
        WHERE `firstname` LIKE '%" . $data . "%'
            OR `lastname` LIKE '%" . $data . "%'
            OR `description` LIKE '%" . $data . "%'
            OR `grade` LIKE '%" . $data . "%'");

    if (! $query){
        echo'Database error: ' . mysql_error();
    }

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $description = $row['description'];
        echo $description;
    }

    exit;
}
```

The problem is that I am not returning any results and instead getting the errors

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax`and`mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given.

I welcome any tips that I can implement and wouuld greatly appreciate it

Comment: Forget optimizing this code until you learn about and fix the gaping [sql injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). You can twiddle this to your hearts' content until it runs faster than superman, but your server is STILL going to get destroyed by the first script kiddy who comes along.

Comment: What is $grade here.. I don't see it defined

Comment: Have you properly set `$grade = "' OR 1=1 --"`? Then after doing so, you should read up on SQL injection.

Comment: You need to make sure that you are selecting on indexed fields. LIKE is very inefficient by nature.

Comment: @jay: indexes won't help, since it's `like' %foo%'`. The only way to make it more efficient is to switch to fulltext indexes+queries.

Comment: The error is not finished, it usually says `...MySQL server version for the right syntax near XXX`. Please post XXX. The query here doesn't seem wrong. (Except for the SQL injection problem.)

Comment: $grade was meant to be $data, typo.

Comment: why not you give the droppable data an id (`<div data-id="123123">..`) such that there is no need for a like query, or anything similar. For the error - *look* at the query you're actually generating.

Comment: What is `$data`? I'm assuming there's an apostrophe in the value?

Comment: Near "Jeremmy Lin ..."%' OR `lastname` LIKE '%'Jeremy Lin' at line 2 @BartFriederichs

Comment: No apostrophe in the value, why do you say that? $data is the html that is dropped. Look at my JSFIDDLE example @MichaelRushton

Comment: `lastname LIKE '%'Jeremy Lin` is an obvious syntax error

Comment: There is an apostrophe, @Octavius -- before the "J" in "Jeremy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query's syntax is valid, that means you have a single quote somewhere in your input data, causing the query to fail with the syntax error.

To solve that you can pass your `$data` through [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) which will escape any quotes, and most importantly prevent SQL Injection.

Even better than escaping would be to use a parameterised query with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

As for optimisation, you can try [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) instead of multiple LIKE's. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in).

Comment: Right, the Irish name problem -- O'Malley -- may be hitting this OQ.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked for help optimizing a MySQL query that does not work.

First, you need to get the query working. The usual procedure to do that is to type your query into a MySQL client (like phpmyadmin) and see what happens.  You may also find that outputting the constructed query with echo will help you see your SQL syntax error.

Second, queries of the form

```
  column LIKE '%matchstring%'
```

simply cannot be optimized. The leading % on the match string means that the MySQL server has to search every row of the column you mentioned to find a match. Indexes don't help this. If you can query like this

```
 column LIKE 'matchstring%'
```

you can use indexes to optimize these searches.

Third, you're using `OR` in your query. The MySQL optimizer doesn't really like OR, and it rescans the table for each one.

You might put this table into the MyISAM access method (if it isn't already) and use FULLTEXT matching.  Try this:

```
  WHERE MATCH (firstname, lastname, description, grade) 
        AGAINST ('matchstring' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This will do the search you want.  You can optimize it with a fulltext index.

Finally, as Marc B pointed out, you *must* fix your SQL injection problem.  Primary schools, never mind secondary schools, are full of people who would love to pwn the grading system.  To find out the hazard, look up "little Johnny Droptables" in a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Place `die;` after `echo'Database error: ' . mysql_error();` and run your code to check what the database error is.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sanitizing user input, this results in getting stray quote characters in your SQL (as proven by your error message). Simple fix can be (escape the string before putting it into the query):

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])){

    // sanitize user input
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tempusers`
        WHERE `firstname` LIKE '%" . $data . "%'
            OR `lastname` LIKE '%" . $data . "%'
            OR `description` LIKE '%" . $data . "%'
            OR `grade` LIKE '%" . $data . "%'");

    if (! $query){
        echo'Database error: ' . mysql_error();
    }

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $description = $row['description'];
        echo $description;
    }

    exit;
}
```

Please read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

About making it more efficient: indexes won't work on fields that you query with `LIKE`.

Further, you are discouraged to use the `mysql_` function, as they are deprecated. Use `mysqli` instead.