# MySQL search multiple words in loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$keywords=array("test","tset");
$matches = implode(',', $keywords);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `reg` WHERE title like in '%$matches%' group by p_title";

$data = mysql_query($sql); 
while($info=mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
Print " {$info['title']}<br /> ";
}
```

I want to write a query like

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `reg` WHERE title like in '%test%' group by p_title";
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `reg` WHERE title like in '%tset%' group by p_title";
```

........

How can I search for each keyword in one query ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT * FROM reg WHERE title like in '%test%' or  title like in '%tset%' group by p_title"
```

Comment: if I have 15 different words in array, should I write a long query for each case ?

Comment: No you have to use loop for that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM reg WHERE title like in '%{$keywords[0]}%' or title like in '%{$keywords[1]}%'
```

I'd advise using a loop for this. Example:

*Note: this is pretty psuedo-ey*

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM reg WHERE title like in ";
foreach ($keyword in $keywords) {
  if (!$keyword is last)
    $query .= "'%$keyword%' or title like in ";
  else $query .= "'%$keyword%' group by p_title"
}
```

then evaluate `$query`

Comment: at the last loop -> '%$keyword%' or title like in group by p_title.. How can I remove the or title like in at the end ?

Comment: @MamasPlodos updated to suit that question

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [MySQL LIKE IN()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in)

```
$keywords=array("test","tset");
$matches = implode('|', $keywords);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `reg` WHERE title REGEXP '%$matches%' group by p_title";

$data = mysql_query($sql); 
while($info=mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
    Print " {$info['title']}<br /> ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `reg` WHERE title ";

$where='';
foreach($keywords as $val)
{
  $where .= "LIKE '%$val%' OR title ";

}
$where = substr($where , 0, -9); // to remove last OR 
$finalSql = $sql .$where;

$data = mysql_query($finalSql);
```

Answer (score 0):

`implode` PHP function allows to implement that without a loop:

```
$keywords=array("test","tset");
$matches = implode("%' OR title LIKE '%", $keywords);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `reg` WHERE title LIKE '%$matches%' group by p_title";

$data = mysql_query($sql); 
while($info=mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
Print " {$info['title']}<br /> ";
}
```