# MySQL query gives wrong result

Tags: mysql

I have to write a MySQL query for fetching result from my database with a specified date and code like ABH18 or ABH17 or ABH19. I write the query like below.

```
select * from tbl_transaction where
  trans_name like 'ABH19%' or trans_name like 'ABH18%' 
  or trans_name like 'ABH17%' or trans_name like 'ABH15%' 
  and date_of_vazhipad='2013-11-20' and trans_status='Completed successfully.'
```

There are no results in the DB satisfying all above conditions.But I got a result with different dates. But I want to ensure the date_of_vazhipad='2013-11-20' so that the query may work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` has a priority over `OR`. Put parentheses in the right places:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_transaction WHERE
(trans_name like 'ABH19%' OR 
 trans_name like 'ABH18%' OR 
 trans_name like 'ABH17%' OR 
 trans_name like 'ABH15%') 
AND date_of_vazhipad='2013-11-20' 
AND trans_status='Completed successfully.'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP` to shorten the query

Regexp is `'^ABH19|^ABH18|^ABH17|^ABH15'`

**i.e.**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_transaction 
  WHERE trans_name REGEXP '^ABH19|^ABH18|^ABH17|^ABH15'
   AND date_of_vazhipad='2013-11-20' 
   AND trans_status='Completed successfully.';
```

Found reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in)