# Operand count error for query using `LIKE`

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL query:

```
 delimiter |
 CREATE FUNCTION KPI17 (s VARCHAR(20000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(20000)
 DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
    DECLARE str  VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE toFind  VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co1 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co2 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co3 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co4 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co5 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co6 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co7 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co8 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co9 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co10 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co11 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co12 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co13 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE co14 VARCHAR(2000);
    DECLARE cpt VARCHAR(20000);
    SET co='';
    SET co1='';
    SET co2='';
    SET co3='';
    SET co4='';
    SET co5='';
    SET co6='';
    SET co7='';
    SET co8='';
    SET co9='';
    SET co10='';
    SET co11='';
    SET co12='';
    SET co13='';
    SET co14='';
    SET cpt='';
    SET str='';
    SET toFind=s;
    SET str =SUBSTRING_INDEX(toFind,'sur',1);
    IF (str like ('%CDR%')) =1 THEN set co1 = 'CDR';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%DL DROP TBF%','%TBF FAIL%','%TBF DROP%','%TBF SR%','%DL TBF SR%','%UL FAIL TBF%','%DATA FAIL%','%FAIL TBF%','%DL DROP DATA%'))=1 THEN set co2 = 'FAIL ET DROP TBF';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%SD DROP%','%SDR%'))=1 THEN set co3 ='SDR';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%FAIL TCH%'))=1 THEN set co4 = 'FAIL TCH';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%HO LEVEL EN DL%','%HO QUALITE%','%HO INTERFERENCE%','%INC HO%'))=1 THEN set co5 = 'DEGRADATION HO';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%DEGRADATION DE TOUS LES KPI CS/PS%','%SLEEPING PS%','%SLEEPING CS%','%BAISSE DE TRAFFIC%'))=1 THEN set co6 = 'DEGRADATION DES KPI CS/PS 2G';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%CSSR%'))=1 THEN set co7 = 'CSSR';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%COUPURE BSS%','%CALL DROP BSS%','%DROP BSS%'))=1 THEN set co8 = 'CALL DROP BSS';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%HSPA DROP%','%HSPA RB DROP%','%HSPA Rb DROP%','%HSPA RAB SETUP%','%HSPA RAB SETUP SR%','%SLEEPING HSPA%','%HSPA SSR%','%HSPA SR%'))=1 THEN set co9 = 'HSPA';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%HSUPA RAB SETUP%','%SLEEPING HSUPA%'))=1 THEN set co10 = 'HSUPA';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%R99 DROP%','%R99 RB DROP%'))=1 THEN set co11 = 'R99';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%RRC SETUP SUCCESS OTHER RATE%','%RRC OTHER%','%RRC OTHERS%','%DEGRADATION RRC CS/PS SETUP%','%RRC SETUP SR%','%RRC SETUP SUCC SERV RATE%','%PS RRC SSR%','%PS RRC SETUP SR%'))=1 THEN set co12 = 'RRC';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%CS RAB%','%CS RAB SETUP%','%CS RAB SETUP SR%','%PS RAB DROP%','%PS RAB SETUP SR%'))=1 THEN set co13 = 'RAB';
    ElSEIF (str like ('%PS DROP%','%CS SERVICE DROP%'))=1 THEN set co14 = 'DEGRADATION DES KPI CS/PS 3G';
    ELSE SET co='vid';END IF;
    set cpt=CONCAT(co,co1,co2,co3,co4,co5,co6,co7,co8,co9,co10,co11,co12,co13,co14);      
return cpt;
END |
delimiter;
```

I used this query where 'title' is the name of the column used and 'test3' is the name of the column where I will store a result:

```
    update incident set test3= KPI17 (title)
```

But I get the following error:

> Error code 1241, SQL state 21000: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

How can I fix this?

Comment: ...if this is going to be done more than once, you'd probably be better off creating a mapping table.  Also, you use multiple variables, but your `ELSEIF` cascade will only output **one** of them (so either you have a bug, or you only need one output variable/just return).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as the error suggests, is that you cannot use multiple values for the `LIKE` operand.

So, instead of having a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE str LIKE ('%this%', '%that%');
```

You'll need to use `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE str LIKE '%this%' OR str LIKE '%that%';
```

Another option, gained from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1127106/3131147) answer is to use a regular expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE str REGEXP 'this|that';
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/426cc/3) example.