# PHP mysql multiple words search query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I made a query for search(max three words) but its not quite helpful when increasing the number of words, hence I need a code for n number of codes

here is [my site](http://job.comeze.com/)

```
 public function search() {
            $s_keywords = $this->input->get('q');           
            $arr = explode(" ", $s_keywords);

            if (count($arr) > 0) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT 
                    vacancy_id, vc_title, vc_experience, vc_closedate, tbl_company_cmp_name 
                    FROM tbl_vacancy
                    WHERE CONCAT(vc_title, ' ', tbl_company_cmp_name)  =  '$s_keywords' ");             
                $result = $query->result();

                return array( 'job_search' => $result,);
            }

            if (count($arr) == 1) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT vacancy_id, vc_title, vc_experience, vc_closedate, tbl_company_cmp_name FROM tbl_vacancy
                WHERE vc_title LIKE '%{$s_keywords}%' OR tbl_company_cmp_name LIKE '%{$s_keywords}%' ");
                $result = $query->result();

                return array( 'job_search' => $result,);
            } else if (count($arr) == 2) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT vacancy_id, vc_title, vc_experience, vc_closedate, tbl_company_cmp_name FROM tbl_vacancy
                WHERE (vc_title LIKE '%{$arr[0]}%' OR tbl_company_cmp_name LIKE '%{$arr[0]}%' ) "
                . "AND (vc_title LIKE '%{$arr[1]}%' OR tbl_company_cmp_name LIKE '%{$arr[1]}%') ");
                $result = $query->result();

                return array( 'job_search' => $result,);
            } else if (count($arr) == 3) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT vacancy_id, vc_title, vc_experience, vc_closedate, tbl_company_cmp_name FROM tbl_vacancy
                WHERE (vc_title LIKE '%{$arr[0]}%' OR tbl_company_cmp_name LIKE '%{$arr[0]}%' ) "
                . "AND (vc_title LIKE '%{$arr[1]}%' OR tbl_company_cmp_name LIKE '%{$arr[1]}%') "
                . "AND (vc_title LIKE '%{$arr[2]}%' OR tbl_company_cmp_name LIKE '%{$arr[2]}%') ");
                $result = $query->result();

                return array( 'job_search' => $result,);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to add much more detail as to what you are looking for.

Comment: @Hanoncs like what? this is my model for search (I'm using codeigniter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4808757/4137738) you need either an OR statement (like you did) or use `REGEXP` for your query.

Either way you need to create the query string and then run the query. I'd loop over each word, e.g.

```
$query = 'SELECT vacancy_id, vc_title, vc_experience, vc_closedate, tbl_company_cmp_name FROM tbl_vacancy';
$wheres = array();

foreach ($arr as $keyword) {
$wheres[] = "vc_title LIKE '%{$skeyword}%' OR tbl_company_cmp_name LIKE '%{$keyword}%' ";
};

//join the where lines with 'AND'
$where = join(' AND ', $wheres);

$query = $query . ' WHERE ' . $where;
//run the query

$query = $this->db->query($query);
$result = $query->result();
return array( 'job_search' => $result,);
```

The same way you can build the regex, we don't need the foreach in this case as we have the single words in the array:

```
$regex = join('|', $arr);
$query = 'SELECT vacancy_id, vc_title, vc_experience, vc_closedate, tbl_company_cmp_name FROM tbl_vacancy';

$where = " WHERE vc_title REGEXP '$regex' OR tbl_company_cmp_name  REGEXP '$regex'";
$query = $this->db->query($query . $where);
$result = $query->result();
return array( 'job_search' => $result,);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$arr = array("sads", "test", "do work");

$q = "SELECT vacancy_id, vc_title, vc_experience, vc_closedate, tbl_company_cmp_name FROM tbl_vacancy WHERE ";
foreach($arr as $a) {
    $q .= "AND (vc_title LIKE '%{$a}%' OR tbl_company_cmp_name LIKE '%{$a}%') ";
}

echo $q;
```