# php and mysql live search

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm currently working on a live search that displays results directly from a mysql db.

The code works, but not really as i want it.

Let's start with an example so that it is easier to understand:

My database has 5 columns:

```
id, link, description, try, keywords
```

The script that runs the ajax request on key up is the following:

```
$("#searchid").keyup(function () {
    var searchid = encodeURIComponent($.trim($(this).val()));
    var dataString = 'search=' + searchid;
        if (searchid != '') {
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "results.php",
              data: dataString,
              cache: false,
              success: function (html) {
                 $("#result").html(html).show();
              }
           });
         }
        return false;
    });
});
```

on the results.php file looks like this:

```
if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

if ($_REQUEST) {
    $q = $_REQUEST['search'];

    $sql_res = "select link, description, resources, keyword from _db where description like '%$q%' or keyword like '%$q%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql_res) or die(mysqli_error($db));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        $display = '<div id="explainMessage" class="explainMessage">Sorry, no results found</div>';
        echo $display;
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $link = $row['link'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $keyword = $row['keyword'];
            $b_description = '<strong>' . $q . '</strong>';
            $b_keyword = '<strong>' . $q . '</strong>';
            $final_description = str_ireplace($q, $b_description, $description);
            $final_keyword = str_ireplace($q, $b_keyword, $keyword);

            $display = '<div class="results" id="dbResults">
                    <div>
                        <div class="center"><span class="">Description :</span><span class="displayResult">' . $final_description . '</span></div>
                        <div class="right"><span class="">Keyword :</span><span class="displayResult">' . $final_keyword . '</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                </div>';
            echo $display;
        }

    }
}
```

now, let's say that i have this row in my DB:

```
id = 1
link = google.com
description = it's google
totry = 0
keywords: google, test, search
```

if i type in the search bar:

```
google, test
```

i have the right result, but if i type:

```
test, google
```

i have no results, as obviously the order is wrong.
So basically, what o'd like to achieve is something a bit more like "tags", so that i can search for the right keywords without having to use the right order.

Can i do it with my current code (if yes, how?) or i need to change something?

thanks in advance for any suggestion.

PS: I know this is not the best way to read from a DB as it has some security issues, i'm going to change it later as this is an old script that i wrote ages ago, i'm more interested in have this to work properly, and i'm going to change method after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Untested code** but modify according to your needs,

```
$q = $_REQUEST['search'];

$q_comma = explode(",", $q);

$where_in_set = '';

$count = count($q_comma);

foreach( $q_comma as $q)
{
    $counter++;
    if($counter == $count) {
         $where_in_set .= "FIND_IN_SET('$q','keywords')";
     }else {
         $where_in_set .= "FIND_IN_SET('$q','keywords') OR ";
     }
}

$sql_res = "select link, description, resources, keyword from _db where $where_in_set or description like '%$q%'";
```

Comment: with this example, when i try to search i get this message: Unknown column '$q' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Nick check my edit now , i used single quote that was the problem

Comment: ok, now the message is a bit different...if i type "test" i get Unknown column 'test' in 'where clause'

Comment: echo your $sql_res and provide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102226/discussion-between-n01ze-and-nick).

Comment: select link, description, keyword from _db where FIND_IN_SET(test,keywords) or description like '%test%'

Answer (score 2):

**Normalize your schema**

The rules of relational database are very simple (at least the first three).

> keywords: google, test, search

...breaks the second rule. Each keyword should be in its own row in a related table. Then you can simply write your query as....

```
SELECT link, description, resources, keyword 
FROM _db 
INNER JOIN keywords 
ON _db.id=keywords.db_id
WHERE keyword.value IN (" . atomize($q) . ")
```

(where atomize explodes the query string, *applies mysqli_escape_paramter() to each entry to avoid breaking your code*, encloses each term in single quotes and concatenates the result).

Alternatively you could use [MySQL's full text indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) which does this for you transparently.

Although hurricane makes some good points in his/her answer, they do not mention that none of the solutions proposed there does not scale to handle large volumes of data with any efficiency (decomposing the field into a new table/using full text indexing does).

Comment: I solved this using the answer i selected, but i think i'm going to give this solution a try as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions I can think of:

1. Use fulltext [index and search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).
2. You can split the search string into words in php for example using explode() and serach for the words not in a single serach criteria, but in separate ones. This latter one can be very resource intensive, since you are seraching in multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

LIKE '%google, test%' will match id=1 but not '%google,test%' (no space between coma) nor '%google test%' (space delimiter) nor '%test, google%'. Put each keyword as separate table or you can split input keywords into several single keyword and use OR operator such as LIKE 'google%' OR LIKE 'test%'

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution, but instead of treating your search datastring as one element, you can have php treat it as an array of keywords separated by a comma (by using explode). You'd then build a query depending on how many keywords were sent.

For example, using "google, test" your query would be:

```
$sql_res = "select link, description, resources, keyword from _db where (description like '%$q1%' or keyword like '%$q1%') AND (description like '%$q2%' or keyword like '%$q2%')";
```

Where $q1 and $q2 are "google" and "test".

Answer (score 0):

First of all as you say **it is not a good way** to do it. I think you are writing a autocompleter.

1. **Seperators for words**

"google, test" or "test, google" is a attached words. First you need to define a seperator for users. Usually it is a  whitespace ' '.

When you define it you need to split words.

```
$words = explode(" ",$q);
// now you get two words "google," and "test"
```

Then you need to create a sql which gives you multiple search chance.

There are a lot example in [MySQL LIKE IN()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in)

Now you get your result.

2. **Text similarity**

Select all result from db and in a while search a text from another text. It gives you a dobule point for similarity. Best result is your result.

[Php Similarity Example](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.similar-text.php)

**Important Info**

If you ask my opinion don't use it like that bcs it is very expensive. Use autocompleters on html side. Here is an [example](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: How can i use an html autocompleter if i have already everything stored into a database? I mean, how would you actually do this using autocompleter with data from the db? do you have any example?

Comment: You can select and send your data as json to html. And you can write a search function which is using this json data.