# MySQL - SELECT w/ php WHERE a field LIKE any element of an array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php and MySQL to display some result to a dynamic website. Now here's an array (generated depends on different input):

```
$myarr = array('aaa','bbb','ccc',...)
```

I want to test in MySQL if there's an existing value in table 'product_info' that is LIKE '%aaa%' or '%bbb%' or '%ccc%', just similar to what we do for IN keyword but with wildcards. If the value exists, I'll grab the row and display it, if not I'll do something else. No clue what the query statement in MySQL would look like.

Could anyone help with the statement?

Comment: Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in) with same question and good answer.

Comment: @VolodymyrNakvasiuk If you find a question with the answer, click on `flag` and report it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try regexp like this:

```
$array = array('aaa','bbb','ccc',...);

$string = implode('|',$array);

mysql_query("SELECT * from table where field REGEXP '".$string."'");
```