# how to search for each line of texarea data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i am taking textarea data which is the "firstname" one below each other and trying to search for those names in mysql database and if the name found in database then display the full information.

This is the code so far, but only works for 1 line data

```
<?php
session_start();
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
          <form method="post">
          <textarea name="search" type="search" list="searchkey" placeholder="search"  class="search"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="click" value="search"  />
<?php
      $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'skfstapel');
          if(isset($_POST['submit']))
           {
              $textarea = trim($_POST['search']);
              $search = implode("|",explode("\r\n", $textarea));
              $_SESSION['firstname']= $textarea;
            }
                if(($_SESSION['firstname']!=""))
                {
                  $view = $db->query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE firstname REGEXP '$search'");
                  $check = $view;
                  if($check!="")
                {
                  while($output = mysqli_fetch_array($view))
                {
              ?>
          <div class="reslt">
            <h3 id="resuil-title">
              <?php echo $output['firstname']; ?>
            </h3>
          <p class="Description">
          <hr>
          </div>
              <?php } } else { ?>
            <p class="error">
              <?php echo $view; ?>
            <p>
              <?php } }  ?>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using " $search = explode('\n', $_POST['search']); " but somehow could not get it to work or used it wrong. Could any one tell  me what am i doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Try  REGEXP in mysql becasue you need to use "IN" statement but you can't combine "IN" with "LIKE"

Comment: this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in

Comment: hi! I edit my code and everything works for one line input but Im trying to get multiple lines in a Textarea post and that does not work.
for example if I search " robin " it searches for robin and it works 
but if I search " robin [newline] rico [newline] charly " it does not work

Comment: try `explode("\r\n", $textarea)`

Comment: thanks that helped a lot :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$textarea = trim($_POST['search']);
$search = implode("|",preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", "",explode("\n", $textarea)));
```

and the MySQL query looks like

```
if(($_SESSION['firstname']!=""))
{
  $view = $db->query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE firstname REGEXP '$search'");
  $check = mysqli_num_rows($view);
}
```