# DBAL cardinality violation error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, dbal

I am getting the 'Cardinality Violation' error, for the following SQL:

*Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: An exception occurred while executing*

```
SELECT p.* FROM mod_products_products p 
LEFT JOIN mod_products_products_categories c_link ON c_link.product_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN mod_products_brands b ON p.brand_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN mod_products_groups vg ON p.variation_id = vg.id 
LEFT JOIN mod_products_categories c ON c_link.category_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN mod_products_group_options vg_o ON vg_o.group_id = vg.id 
LEFT JOIN mod_products_group_values vg_o_v ON vg_o_v.option_id = vg_o.id 
WHERE (p.name LIKE (?, ?)) AND (p.parent_id = 0) AND (vg_o.disabled=0) 
GROUP BY p.id ORDER BY p.name ASC 
LIMIT 18446744073709551615 OFFSET 0
```

*with params ["%big%", "%light%"]: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s).*

The error only occurs if there is more than one value defined in the parameter list for `WHERE (p.name LIKE (?, ?))`.

I am using `executeQuery()`, and passing the array as `Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY`. In the original statement I am defining the trouble point as:

```
$builder->andWhere('p.name LIKE (:partial_names)');
```

It seems it doesn't like getting an array passed as partial_names. Any ideas on what is causing this, and how to avoid it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in

Comment: What made you think that mysql LIKE can accept more than one argument?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Since `foo LIKE ('bar')` is valid in MySQL, I think it's natural to think `foo LIKE ('bar', 'baz')` would also be valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MySQL LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) is a "string comparison function" and as such compares one string to another, using "simple pattern matching".

If you check the [SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2003), you'll notice that the [BNF grammar for `LIKE`](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#xref-LIKE) accepts only "character-like" and "octet-like" arguments, both of which are essentially what we'd call strings. (There is some detail around the fact that `LIKE` performs a binary, character-for-character match on the RHS, which is different than how `=` operates: `foo LIKE 'bar'` and `foo='bar'` may produce different results.)

All this means you *can't* do `LIKE ('a', 'b')` because the columnar expression `('a', 'b')` is not string-like. Or in geeky standard language, it's cardinality (2) differs from the expected cardinality (1). However, you can do this in MySQL and SQLite (maybe other engines):

```
WHERE foo LIKE ('%bar')
```

because the cardinality of the RHS is 1 (there is one column), which is what `LIKE` expects.

You're wanting something effectively similar to `foo LIKE IN ('a', 'b')`, but that doesn't exist either (for the SQL standard reason mentioned above). [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1127088/2908724) shows some workarounds for that behavior, `REGEXP` based being the accepted answer.

So, to get around this error, you need to rewrite your query to use multiple `LIKE`, or a `REGEXP`, or maybe even something like [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
(p.name LIKE (?, ?))
```

to

```
(p.name LIKE ? OR p.name LIKE ?)
```

and

```
["%big%", "%light%"]
```

to

```
"%big%", "%light%"
```