# selecting multiple values in like operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `SW_TBL_KEYWORD`

```
Keyword       
-------
 ATOP
 APMT
 RSND
```

This is my test query

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @string = 'ATOP,APMT'  

SELECT * 
FROM SW_TBL_KEYWORD 
WHERE Keyword LIKE @string
```

so i need to pass those multiple values which comes from backend to `like` operator. Test query is not working.

HELP!!!

Comment: you can try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in

Comment: Are you sure, you are using `mysql` ? It looks like `sqlserver` code.

Comment: @Susang Yes, it does look like SQL Server.  Oops.

Comment: yes i have edited. its sql server

Comment: Which version of `sqlserver` are you using ??

Comment: Sql Server 2014 version 12.0

Answer (score 0):

the way you tried it works only with Mysql's "IN" function!

That means you have to do it like

```
select * from SW_TBL_KEYWORD where Keyword like "ATOP" OR Keyword LIKE "APMT"..
```

also to mention, that you can use % before, after or before and after so for example

```
select * from SW_TBL_KEYWORD where Keyword like "%TO%"
```

will also give you the result "ATOP"..

So if you want to search for more then one word, you will have to build your query dependinung on the number of words!

I dont know exactly how you get your search terms, but if you get it seperated with an "," you can explode that and then literate over it and create your query!

Comment: the vaues are dynamic, comes from a dropdownlist, this is just a test and its a sql server query, my bad i added mysql as a tag.. i have actually passed multiple values to the parameter from the dropdownlist, now i have to use like operator or any other relevant one to execute the query. help!

Comment: and yes i'd like to mention, i have used Replace function to iterate but for no avail.

Answer (score 0):

will you just replace `like @string` with `REGXP REPLACE(@string, ",", "|")` to achieve what you want

```
select * from SW_TBL_KEYWORD where Keyword REGXP REPLACE(@string, ",", "|")
```

Comment: The question is about **SQL Server** (Microsoft's RDBMS) - which does **NOT** have a `REGXP` operator/function

Comment: @marc_s The original question had tagged MySQL.  I will delete this now.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** for the permanent and flexible solution

Create function `Split` to achieve this requirement and future use also

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
```

Your table and values

```
DECLARE @SW_TBL_KEYWORD TABLE(Keyword VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO @SW_TBL_KEYWORD VALUES
('ATOP'),
('APMT'),
('RSND')
```

Logic to achieve your requirement

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @string='ATOP,APMT'
```

Split the comma separated value using function you have created and store in table variable or in temporary table

```
DECLARE @tmp_filter TABLE(keyword VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO @tmp_filter
SELECT s FROM dbo.Split(',', @string)
```

Join the filter table with actual table using `Like` but after seeing your filter and actual values I think you want the exact match instead of partial using `like`

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM @SW_TBL_KEYWORD t1 
INNER JOIN @tmp_filter t2 ON t1.Keyword LIKE ('%' + t2.keyword + '%')
```

For exact match we can change the join with below line

```
INNER JOIN @tmp_filter t2 ON t1.Keyword = t2.keyword
```

**NOTE**: this is long term solution and useful for the other similar tasks. If you were using `SQLSERVER2016 or newest` then you coluld use `STRING_SPLIT` function instead of creating user defined function.