# MySQL like with IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql-like, sql-in

Is it possible to extend a LIKE expression with an IN clause?

At the moment I got the following SQL:

```
select * 
from SECURITY_PERMISSION permission
where permission.PERMISSION_ID like '%_10498_%'
and permission.PERMISSION_ID like '%_OBJ_VIEW%'
```

I want to pass a list of Numbers to my like expression. Something like that:

```
select * 
from SECURITY_PERMISSION permission
where permission.PERMISSION_ID like '%_IN(list_of_numbers)_%'
and permission.PERMISSION_ID like '%_OBJ_VIEW%'
```

Comment: With like no, however you may be able to do this via regex (`|` operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is bad database design. But you can use `REGEXP` instead:

```
WHERE permission.PERMISSION_ID REGEXP '_(123|456|789)_'
```

It is still bad database design.

Comment: yes it is a bad design ;-) but I it's not designed by me, I just have to work with it.....

Comment: For more details you can check david-carroll answer from this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in

Answer (score 1):

You can also use REGEXP like this, for a field contains multiple values seperated by comma for example:

```sql
WHERE column REGEXP '[[:<:]]1|2|3|4[[:>:]]'
```