# What is right syntax of write query with LIke and Any Operator?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a application in node and sequelize, i run the function that generate the query like below

```
SELECT `id`, `product_title`, `product_size`, `product_author`, `description`, `product_category`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `products` AS `products` WHERE `products`.`product_category` LIKE ANY ('%Shirts%', '%Jeans%', '%Pents%')
```

But it gives me syntax error, what is going wrong in this query, because i never use this query before.

Please help me to find the error.

Comment: You can't use `LIKE` with `ANY`

Comment: use `LIKE` with `OR`

Comment: @Nick So can you give me any solution for find the data match from array

Comment: [MySQL LIKE IN()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in)

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie definitely a dupe...

Comment: @RobinSingh see the question Anant posted in their comment