# Array of String Search in express.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I have array of string like this

```
let search = ["user","country"];
```

I want to get data from  mysql database using `LIKE` operator.

For example like this

```
searchStmnt = `u.u_fullname LIKE "%` + search + `%"`
```

But the above code is not working. Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Comment: you should use [IN](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php) operator and look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const search = ["user", "country"];
const searchStmnt = search.map(item => `u.u_fullname LIKE '%${item}%'`).join(" OR ");
console.log(searchStmnt);
```

...or with `REGEXP`:

```js
const search = ["user", "country"];
const searchStmnt = `u.u_fullname REGEXP '(${search.join("|")})'`;
console.log(searchStmnt);
```