# Convert sql to JPA with a in-clause and a list of like

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a sql statement as below and want to convert it to JPA

```sql
SELECT * FROM employee
where user_id in ('id1', 'id2', 'id3')
AND (
    first_name like '%name1%' OR last_name like '%name1%'
    OR
    first_name like '%name2%' OR last_name like '%name2%'
    )
ORDER BY user_id ASC;
```

---

**Input parameter**

userIdList - a list of string to exact match user_id of size [1,100]

nameList - a list of string to like-wise match first_name or last_name of size [1,100] in character [A-Za-z0-9-_ ]

example for name list: ['Joe', 'Peter', 'White', 'X Y']

---

I have no idea about how to handle the List of like part and the closest I have is without the list of like

```java
@Modifying
@Query(value = "select * from employee where user_id IN :ids ORDER BY user_id",
            nativeQuery = true)
List<UserGroupTable> findAllByUserIdList(@Param("ids") List<String> userIdList);
```

In clause reference: [%Like% Query in spring JpaRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18987480/3759505)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex query could be one way to achieve this, as described here:
[Searching multiple colums with a Contains query with a list of Items in Spring-Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69373878/searching-multiple-colums-with-a-contains-query-with-a-list-of-items-in-spring-d/69384268#69384268)

Sample for `MariaDB`/`MySQL`:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM my_entity WHERE "
      + "first_name REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', :nameslist) " + "OR "
      +  "last_name REGEXP CONCAT_WS('|', :nameslist) ")
    List<MyEntity> findByNames( // (method name does not matter)
                     @Param("nameslist") Collection<String> nameslist);
```

(`CONCAT_WS` joins the provided list, e.g. `('val1', 'val2', 'val3')` to the regex `'val1|val2|val3'`, which would match e.g. 'complete`val2`xxx'.)

Note that the exact REGEXP / CONCAT_WS functions depend on the used DB.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the intention is for `name1` and `name2` to also be parameters, you only need to finish out your JPA query:

```
select *
from employee
where user_id IN :ids and (
      first_name like :name1 or last_name like :name1 or
      first_name like :name2 or last_name like :name2)
order by user_id
```

Your updated Java method:

```java
@Modifying
@Query(value = "select * from employee where user_id IN :ids and (first_name like :name1 or last_name like :name1 or first_name like :name2 or last_name like :name2) order by user_id",
    nativeQuery = true)
List<UserGroupTable> findAllByUserIdList(@Param("ids") List<String> userIdList, @Param("name1") String name1, @Param("name2") String name2);
```

Note carefully here that you bind to `:name1` and `:name2` the actual wildcard expression.  E.g. for a name of `John Doe`, you would bind `%John%` and `%Doe%` to the two placeholders.

Comment: name1 and name2 are list of name to match, not exactly 2. Let me update my question to make it more clear

Comment: @hk6279 ... you can't bind a list to a SQL `LIKE` expression.

Comment: if it is impossible to do it by JPA, then I could do a in clause and handle the like clause by java code. Just want to check if this is possible before I move to java logic.

Comment: Tough one, because `IN` cannot be used with `LIKE`.